# Using Knockout Mapping with JSON containing Hypermedia Links

Tags: knockout.js, hateoas

I'm using a RESTful WebAPI service to return JSON with Hypermedia links and then tried to use KnockoutJS mapping to decode into the view model and it keeps failing although don't understand why. Am having to manually parse the stringified JSON which means my client has now become object specific removing the flexibility with the solution I was after.

The simplified example below returns the details of a single restaurant with a couple of actions to either book or email.

Here is the JSON

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Kings Head",
    "NickName": "Kings",
    "_links": {
        "book": {
            "href": "/resturant/1/book",
            "title": "Book"
        },
        "email": {
            "href": "/resturant/1/email",
            "title": "Email"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "/resturant/1"
        }
    }
}
```

The code that works is:

```
var viewModel = {
   Name: ko.observable(),
   NickName: ko.observable()
};

$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/resturants/1', function (jsonResult) {
   var str = JSON.stringify(jsonResult);
   var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
   viewModel.Name = (parsed.Name);
   viewModel.NickName = (parsed.NickName);
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
})
```

If I attempt to use:

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonResult);
```

it fails.

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks,

Shaun

Comment: What kind of error does it give you when it fails? That should show up in the debugger console. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the callback and manually inspecting `jsonResult` to make sure it's the proper data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `jsonResult` straight from the service call, which I assume you are, then you need `viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonResult);` Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5e5GB/) with each scenario setup.

Comment: Many thanks, answer was indeed `codeviewModel=ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonResult)` and then to apply bindings. Appreciate the help.